# Protecting Flask-Admin Routes using Flask-Praetorian

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-admin, flask-praetorian

I am using [`Flask-Praetorian`](https://flask-praetorian.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to provide my Flask API server with user authentication and route protection features.

After installing `Flask-Admin` to the app, I notice that the `/admin` routes are not protected by user authentication.

How can we use `Flask-Praetorian` to secure the routes of `Flask-Admin`?

*Using Python 3.7.4, Flask 1.1.1, flask-praetorian 1.0.0, Flask-Admin 1.5.4, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.1*

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_praetorian import Praetorian
from flask_admin import Admin

db = SQLAlchemy()
guard = Praetorian()
admin = Admin()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    ...


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    db.init_app(app)
    guard.init_app(app, User)
    admin.init_app(app)

    # Example of protected route
    @app.route('/protected', methods=['GET'])
    @auth_required
    def protected():
        return jsonify({'logged_in': 'true'})

    return app
```

Comment: You can use `flask_praetorian.auth_required` decorator for your protected route

Comment: @MartinValentino How can the decorator be added to the Flask-admin routes? I am not sure how to access/declare those routes so that the decorator can be added to them

Comment: You may need to create an override view for the admin view and put the decorator there as described in this api docs https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/